# x509 SSL error while launching spring-boot and docker

Tags: docker, maven, ssl, certificate, x509

This is the mvn command line I launch :

```
mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true 
    -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true clean install spring-boot:build-image
```

This is the error I get :

```
Get "https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/8u252+9/bellsoft-jre8u252+9-linux-amd64.tar.gz": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have tried many workaround but it seems that I couldn't solve the issue.

Any idea ?

Comment: Same here. Behind a corporate wall with BlueCoat agent. Trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as stated above, in a corporate world with additional agents, I had to configure Docker to run with a proxy.
[image: Docker Manual Proxy]